# How to update imshow in matplotlib without overwriting new color bar or subplot title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-2.7

**Background:** I am working an a data processing application and am trying to visualize 2D arrays with matplotlib embedded into a tkinter gui. I am trying to update the matplotlib figure by collecting user input (i.e. what frame they want displayed, various other options) so I do not want to generate the animation in advance.

**System:** Windows xp, Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.1.1rc

**Question:** How do I update only the image produced by imshow and not the colorbar?

**GUI**
[image: gui snapshot]
*Notice how color bars write over themselves.*

**Code:** *note: the code below is untested, however it is the basic idea of how my current code is setup*

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import Tkinter as tk
import numpy as np


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self,application):
        self.mainframe=tk.Frame(application)

        #update button
        ttk.Button(application,text='Update',command=self.update).pack()

        #matplotlib setup
        self.ren2DFig=plt.figure(figsize=(4,4),dpi=100)
        self.renCanvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.ren2DFig,master=self.renWin2D)
        self.renCanvas.show()
        self.renCanvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        self.subPlot=self.ren2DFig.add_subplot(111)
        self.subPlot.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.subPlot.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.subPlot.get_axes().set_frame_on(False)
        frame=np.zeros((20,40),)
        frame[9:11 ,9:11]=1
        frame[5 ,5]=.5
        self.im=self.subPlot.imshow(self.rotate(frame), origin = 'lower')
        self.cbar=self.ren2DFig.colorbar(self.im)
        self.cbar.set_label('Solid Fraction')
        self.renCanvas.draw()
        self.ren2DFig.canvas

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_array(np.zeros((20,40),))
        self.renCanvas.draw() # I think this is the problem?

application=tk.Tk()
application.focus_force()
window=MainWindow(application)
application.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",window.close)
application.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**Update**[July 13, 2012]:

If I try clearing the subplot, then adding the image and color bar back, finally re-drawing the canvas I get this:

[image: matplotlib]

What the heck am I doing wrong?????? This is really starting to irritate me.

Comment: Offtopic, but did you develop the GUI yourself from scratch or is the "foundation" available as open source somewhere? If so, maybe you could share a link? This seems to be similar to what I need...

Comment: @Vitto, I developed the GUI myself from scratch. After I got it mostly working I discovered a much better way to do it using Qt (PySide or PyQt) and pyqtgraph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will have to take a look at that!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but would you say it is relatively easy to load a sequence of images? Assuming you have experience with Qt designer, is it possible to do it there with minimal Pyhton code edition?

Comment: It is pretty easy to load images in Qt. You can email me at [onlyjus at gmail com] if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. The problem is with

```
self.subPlot.get_axes().set_frame_on(False)
```

I guess it is a bug or something but if I change it to True, i.e.

```
self.subPlot.get_axes().set_frame_on(True)
```

It works just fine, everything updates like normal.

This little thing stumped me for two days!!! Go figure. lol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the behaviour you are seeing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.ion()

data = numpy.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
im = plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar(im)
im.set_array(5-data)
# re-draw now that we have changed the data array
plt.draw()
```

Updates the image without modifying the colorbar. Could you explain further the problem you are having?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. However it doesn't seem to be working? Is it the because I have it embedded in Tkinter? i.e. `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. Simply calling `plt.draw()`does not update the figure.